# Did sass have any systax that move class to another nested class?

Tags: sass

My problem is sass nested class become mutiple, it's not easy to maintain.

```
// sass input
.a {

}

.b {
   // some sass syntax here
   color: red;
}
```

I want to move `.b` to `.a` nested. Like below.

```
// css output

.a {
   .b {
       color: red;
   }
}
```

Comment: You could use `@at-root .a &` insidee `.b`.

Comment: Read about [mixins](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin).